# How to imitate "hot" sorting on database data

Tags: typescript, postgresql, prisma

I have a **PostgreSQL** database, which I connect to using prisma ORM, with these two tables:

```
~ Post ~
| id | name | ... | timestamp |
| -- | ---- | --- | --------- |
|  1 |  Foo | ... |      1234 |
|  2 |  Bar | ... |       123 |
```

```
~ Post vote ~
| user_id | post_id |
| ------- | ------- |
|       6 |       1 |
|      15 |       1 |
|      13 |       2 |
```

I'd like to retrieve `n` posts sorting by a combination of **votes count** and **post age**, similarly to what many sites mark as sorting by *hot*. What is a practical way of achieving this?

Looking on [prisma docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/filtering-and-sorting) I have only managed to sort by latest and by votes count, but not by a combination of the two.

Comment: It is up to you to define what you consider hot.

Comment: If I have a function that returns the relevancy score, like relevancy(votes, age), is there a way to use it to sort the data?

Comment: `ORDER BY relevancy(votes, age)`

Comment: I'll try this way then. I hoped there was some way to use prisma standard queries filters/sorting, but this is fine as well. Thank you